# How to get each string from file.txt in md5sum?

Tags: linux, bash

I have file.txt:

```
string1
string2
string3
string4
```

How I can get each string in md5sum using follow command(?):

```
... | md5sum | sed -r 's/(..){3}/\1:/g;s/\s+-$//'
```

I trying this:

```
cat file.txt | md5sum | sed -r 's/(..){3}/\1:/g;s/\s+-$//'
```

...but this is fail way.

Comment: Are newline characters terminators that should be dropped? Or should each string contain the trailing newline?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski without newline char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s' "$line" | md5sum
done <file.txt | sed -r 's/(..){3}/\1:/g;s/\s+-$//'
```

This will read lines from `file.txt` and send them one by one, each to a separate `md5sum`. Single `sed` processes all the output; there's no point in running one `sed` per line.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works!